# An element triggers a mouseout or mouseleave event when hovering over a child input text field contained within the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

**This bug is in Chrome only.**

I have a div that contains an input text field. By default, the div is hidden and is shown on a button click event and hides on a mouseleave event.

In Chrome, if you hover over the containing text field, the mouseout/mouseleave event gets triggered and the div hides.

Steps for reproducing:

- Open up http://jsfiddle.net/2AKAp/3/ in Chrome
- Click on button to show the div
- Hover over anywhere in the div outside the text field and it should not hide
- Hover over the text field and the div hides

Just wondering if this is something you have come across before.

---

Here is the bug filed with the Chromium team that is tracking this issue:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68861

Looks like this is a bug with Chrome and it has been fixed. The fix will be rolled out with version 11 it seems.

Comment: I saw this recently as well. A bug report for Chrome might be worthwhile, as well.

Comment: You might want to try using [hoverintent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) if you need a work around.

Comment: The mouseout would still fire when you hover over the textfield, and no mousein will fire. Therefore, hoverintent would only delay the hiding.

Comment: I used contenteditable=true with a span to overcome that problem. Feels good to know that it's not just me.